# PermissionTabSetting - Masking Name values in VF/Aura

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, permission-sets

We have a requirement to pull the report for tab level access. However it is working weird.

Following query is **working in anonymous window** or in **class if its called from another class** and **giving proper results**.

```sql
SELECT   Name,Visibility ,Parent.Profile.Name
FROM     PermissionSetTabSetting 
WHERE    parent.isOwnedByProfile = true
```

However if I try to **execute the same query from Lightning(Aura), VF page, Remote Action** it is **masking name values and giving IDs with prefix 01r**(which is **CustomTabDefinition**).

***Is there any alternative ways to fetch the data without getting names masked in Lightning/VF/JS.?***